Converting Memory Output from Ki to MB with JSON Path Query Output
I am running the below query to get two outputs across two columns :
Name
Memory
But the memory output is shown in Ki. I would like to convert the output of the node memory into MB when it is displayed.
How do i format my JSON path query to achieve this?
My current query :
kubectl get no  -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,MEMORY:.status.capacity.memory



Not sure how kubernetes is using it, but JSON Path is query only.  It doesn't support transformations, whether structurally or by value.

kubectl get no -o=custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,MEMORY:.status.capacity.memory | awk 'NR==1 {print $0} NR>1 {printf "%-30s %-10.2f MB\n", $1, $2/1024}' 
Example is not pure json query (using awk and pipe), or maybe jq can be used

kubectl get hpa-o json it fetches the Horizontal Pod Autoscaling(HPA) resource in JSON format.
You can try using ‘jq’ command like below :

kubectl get hpa-o json | jq -r ‘.items[] | [.metadata.name,(.status.currentMetrics[] | select(.resource.name==”memory”).resource.current.averageValue' | tonumber / (1024*1024) | tostring + “MB”)] | @tsv

Jq processes the JSON output. @tsv for tab-separated values for better visibility. It is in a decimal place. And if you are working with linux, by using numfmt (which converts numbers from/to human-readable format ) also we can get.

kubectl get hpa-o custom-columns=”MEMORY:status.currentMetrics1.resource.current.averageValue'' -- no-headers | numfmt --to=iec

And also refer to the Ostechnix article written by SK on The Numfmt Command tutorial for more details. It is in the format of human readable form with IEC standard.

@Pallab Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your issue? If not, I am happy to assist further.What should I do when someone answers my question?
